How to construct a propositional logic formula to enforce a certain relation?
Disclaimer: this is a question from a homework but i am really struggling with it and would like to get some help.
I have a set of students $S$, set of Time-slots $T$,set of cookies $P$ and the relation $M \subseteq (S\times P)$ where each tuple means that the student likes that cookie type. now i need to construct a formula which holds true if and only if the following condition(s) also hold true:
Each student must be invited to exactly one time slot, and has at least one alternative slot.
I built a formula for the condition that each student is invited to exactly one like this:
$\beta(E_{s,t}) = 
\begin{cases}
    1, & \text{if student $s$ is invited to time slot t} \\
    0, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$
$\varphi_i := \bigwedge\limits_{s \in S} \left(\bigvee\limits_{t \in T} \left(
    E_{s,t} \land \bigwedge\limits_{\substack{t' \in T \\ t' \neq t}}
    \neg E_{s,t'}\right)\right)$
However, I know that this is only my interpretation of the variable $E_{s,t}$ and not what the formula enforces. meaning, I think i need to make sure that each student really gets a time slot, but I am not sure how to do that. If I had a relation that tells me which time slot each student has, then i could've said that for each pair (s',t') in that relation, $E_{s',t'}$ must happen. But I am not allowed to add any new sets:/
